# c++ accesse violation while trying to open camera when debugging

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "vfw32.lib")
#pragma comment( lib, "comctl32.lib" )
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat edges;
    VideoCapture cap;
    try
    {
        cap.open(0); // open the default camera
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        cout << "error!!" << endl;
    }
    if (!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
        return -1;
    namedWindow("edges", 1);
    for (;;)
    {
        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
        edges = frame;
        GaussianBlur(edges, edges, Size(7, 7), 1.5, 1.5);
        imshow("edges", edges);
        if (waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

when i try to run this code in the command line it runs perfectly, but when i try to debug it in visual studio express 2013 it crashing at the line "cap.open(0);"
the errror is :

Unhandled exception at 0x0C028EFB in opencv_1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x0C028EFB.

i dont know what the problem is or how to fix it. 
sorry for bad english

Comment: Are you linking against the debug versions of the opencv lib files in your debug mode project?

Comment: yeah i checked it twice, actually when i moved the whole project to a diffrent computer and tried to debug it, it worked!